# Javascript get html dom through variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

Recently, when I am working on some javascript code, I found that I can get a html dom by using a variable which has the same name with the html dom's ID property. For example:

`<input type="hidden" id="foo" value="100">`


`console.log(foo.value);`

I can get the value of foo dom. The result is 100.
The question is: **Is it a syntax sugar from browser(some javascript parser such as V8)? Can I get doms by this way?**

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: not following you... what is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This same thing works in my Chrome browser, but I wouldn't imagine this is standardized in any way. Don't depend on this method working in all browsers or in the same way.

Comment: Question seems clear and concise. I'm curious about this behaviour too.

Comment: Is that code actually true? Or pseudo? Can you paste actual code you have received that for? This doesn't make sense. JS will register forms with names to variables, but not like this

Comment: @ChenAsraf Yes, it's easy to check: http://jsfiddle.net/AniHouse/hvaxqjvn/

Comment: **There is nothing related to engine its because element ID are a global property , but this is not a correct and safe way although correct way access value via 'this' by passing it as a argument**



     <input id="ids" value="test" onclick="foo(this)" />

    // Javascript
    function foo(elem){
        var value = elem.value;
    var id    = elem.id;
    }

 or by document.getElementById('ids');

:)

Comment: @Dalorzo thanks for your comment, question has been updated